# Non-EU citizen spouse, working in other EU countries on project-based contracts

Tags: eu-spouses, self-employment

I am an actress (non-EU national), married to an EU citizen, currently living and working in the UK.

Can I apply for auditions/parts in other EU countries on my own right? I am self-employed, and the nature of the profession means that any job is done on fixed term contracts.

Is there a place where I can find information on how the rules work for people working as independent workers in arts/film areas? I've been searching but cannot find information related to that.

Thank you!

Comment: You can apply, but you will have to qualify to work under the specific conditions of each of those countries unless your partner is actually moving to the country permanently with you.